# Buildroot Package needs a toolchain w/C++, largefile error

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, toolchain, buildroot

I am having an issue with getting some new packages into my buildroot configuration. I have manually added the wvdial and wvstreams packages and have them showing up in my make menuconfig. But I am unable to select them to add them to the build because of the following error (can be seen in the image):

[(wvdial, wvstreams) needs a toolchain w/C++, largefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYj0W.png)

I am clueless as to solving this as I have the C++ option selected under the toolchain options as can also be seen in the below image:

[Toolchain Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knIhj.png)

Any help would be much appreciated as I've spent quite a lot of time attempting to resolve this by tinkering and google searching but to no avail.

Also, if this is under the wrong area please let me know so I can change it or a mod can move it automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

largefile requirement was removed from buildroot:

```
commit f526c75f3994acdd58c80afc15aba0789917502f
Author: Gustavo Zacarias <gustavo@zacarias.com.ar>
Date:   Mon Mar 30 18:07:33 2015 -0300

package/uclibc: drop BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_LARGEFILE

Kill the option to build the non-largefile variant and remove the hidden
option since it's now unused.

Signed-off-by: Gustavo Zacarias <gustavo@zacarias.com.ar>
Signed-off-by: Thomas Petazzoni <thomas.petazzoni@free-electrons.com>
```

so you probably need to remove that dependency in your Config.in

br,